# Remove white background after using gdal2tiles

Tags: transparency-opacity, gdal2tiles

I'm using gdal2tiles in a orthomosaic image exported from metashape. When exporting I select to add the alpha channel as you can see below, but after running gdal2tiles I get a white background instead of the alpha channel transparency layer. How can I change that?

```
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 25682x25177, 12841x12589, 6421x6295, 3211x3148, 1606x1574, 803x787, 402x394, 201x197
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
  Overviews of mask band: 25682x25177, 12841x12589, 6421x6295, 3211x3148, 1606x1574, 803x787, 402x394, 201x197
  Unit Type: metre
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 25682x25177, 12841x12589, 6421x6295, 3211x3148, 1606x1574, 803x787, 402x394, 201x197
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
  Overviews of mask band: 25682x25177, 12841x12589, 6421x6295, 3211x3148, 1606x1574, 803x787, 402x394, 201x197
  Unit Type: metre
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 25682x25177, 12841x12589, 6421x6295, 3211x3148, 1606x1574, 803x787, 402x394, 201x197
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
  Overviews of mask band: 25682x25177, 12841x12589, 6421x6295, 3211x3148, 1606x1574, 803x787, 402x394, 201x197
  Unit Type: metre
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Overviews: 25682x25177, 12841x12589, 6421x6295, 3211x3148, 1606x1574, 803x787, 402x394, 201x197
  Unit Type: metre
```

Comment: I actually found out the answer for my problem. I converted my tiff file to png using the following command (gdalwarp -srcnodata 0 imputfile.tiff outputfile.png). Follwing with tilling (gdal2tiles.py -z 18-22 outputfile.png)